# aframe/animation : how to pause and resume?

Tags: aframe

I have a 360° rotation animation in aframe (ar.js) and I would like to pause and continue it, whereas all that I can do it's pause but restart from the begining.

```
<a-entity>
    <a-entity
        gltf-model="#tree-gltf">
    </a-entity>
    <a-animation
        begin="rotation-begin"
        end="rotation-end"
        attribute="rotation"
        to="0 360 0"
        direction="alternate"
        dur="10000"
        repeat="indefinite">
    </a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

[Animation documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/animations.html) give access to "begin" and "end" events, but "begin" restart from the begining and not from the current value when paused.

[Entity documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/entity.html) give access to pause() and play(), which are the same. Play() doesn't work at all if "begin" attribute exist, so you have to choose between events or functions.
But play() also restart animation from the begining and not from where the animation was paused.

I also tried an ugly trick by setting attribute "dur" to one hour to slow down animation so it looks like paused, but setting back "dur" to 10 sec doesn't restart it.

Any idea which can help ?

Comment: have you tried using `fill=forwards` with the animation? That may set the new value before the animation pauses, so it wont reset when the animation restarts again. Otherwise, you might be able to use fill with another animation all together

Comment: fill=forward is the default value, so yes.
I also tried all other values with no success as it defines the position of the frame once stopped/paused, not what to do when restarted.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using Kevin Ngo's `animation-component` helps as it properly supports pause/resume.

Besides including the component, your code will look like this:

```
<a-entity
    animation="property:rotation; startEvents:rotation-begin; pauseEvents: rotation-pause; resumeEvents: rotation-resume; to:0 360 0; dir:alternate; dur:10000; repeat:indefinite"
    gltf-model="#tree-gltf">
</a-entity>
```

This will give you three events: `rotation-begin`, `rotation-pause` and `rotation-resume` that you can trigger.

[See a demo here](https://quickest-manx.glitch.me/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the [link](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation/) on top of the Aframe/Animation doc. It does the job see [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MadsenFr/pen/ZaoXEM) where I replaced "repeat:indefinite" by "loop:true" and also use restartEvents.